# Does using the getx with a stateful widget in flutter cause any performance issues?

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I am building a flutter application and I want to use a stateful widget in my project and want to use the [getx](https://pub.dev/packages/get) library for state management. I was wondering if there is going to be any performance

Comment: no performance issue whatsoever.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No performance issues at all. Preferring using stateful widgets with pages using textformfield even it have GetX.

Update : **Don't use GetX for overall production-level projects. I clearly not recommending the package as it is been made issues over production**, but you can use for minimizing code in some parts, Navigation or in your personal projects.

Refer the Reddit discussion to know more cons about GetX.

[Reddit Discussion](https://www.reddit.com/r/FlutterDev/comments/po1bei/why_is_getx_such_a_bad_state_management/?rdt=44451)

Comment: Thanks, Sree I am now using getx controller which I am injecting into the stateful widget.